# Converting an array of string into integer using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to convert an array of strings into an array of integers in jquery.

Here is my attempt:

```
var cdata = data.values.split(",");
$.each( cdata, function(i, l){
   l = parseInt(l);
});
```

Comment: I'm sure that with a tiny bit of thought you can do it yourself. Think about it. Think about it really hard.

Comment: why use jquery in this case when a simple javascript loop would be sufficient?

What is the goal in using jQuery?

Comment: You really should avoid [calling parseInt() without specifying a radix](http://codethink.no-ip.org/wordpress/archives/394).

Comment: I agree about always specifying a `parseInt()` radix, but I'd also suggest that `parseInt()` is the wrong choice except where you specifically want to deal with non-base-10 numbers or where you want to ignore non-digit characters at the end of the source string. Pablo's answer incorporates just one of the better options.

Answer (score 19):

I think that you not need use Jquery for this case.
In javascript pure:

`var str = "1,2,3";

var ArrayOfInts = str.split(',').map(Number); //Output: [1,2,3]`

Answer (score 8):

```
// Use jQuery
$('.usesJQuery');

// Do what you want to acomplish with a plain old Javascript loop
var cdata = data.values.split(",");
for(var i = 0; i < cdata.length; i++)
    cdata[i] = parseInt(cdata[i], 10);
```

Comment: Or just: `cdata[i] = +cdata[i];`. But the excercise seems rathter pointless since strings can be converted to numbers in the expression that needs them as numbers.

Comment: `+foo` is a shorthand for `parseInt(foo, 10)`

Comment: Not really, if `foo = '10 dollars';` then `parseInt()` works but `+` doesn't.

Comment: Also `parseInt()` is a bit more clear/readable than a unary `+`, in my opinion.  Conciseness isn't everything.

Comment: @Pablo - no, it isn't!! It is more closely equivalent to `Number(foo)` since if `foo = '12px'`, then `parseInt(foo,10)` gives `12` but `+foo` gives `NaN`.

Comment: `+` can also return floating point Numbers while `parseInt` will truncate. So the behavior is only equivalent if you know beforehand that you are converting a string containing only an integer.

Comment: `+foo` is a shorthand for `new Number`

Comment: @The Mask `+"1"` :P That makes more sense

Comment: No reason to hate on jQuery (or underscore.js or whatever). It gives you a cross-browser `.map()` which makes for much cleaner code.

Comment: @Ricardo Better is Subjective :) I'm not hating on jQuery, I use it lots, but something this simple doesn't need it, that's all.

Comment: I changed 'better' to 'cleaner' to clarify :) IMO it's more readable > mantainable > less error-prone. Doesn't hurt if you already have it on the page (90% chance).

Comment: the first lines are awesome +1

Answer (score 6):

```
var cdata = data.values.split(",");
$.map( cdata, function(i, l){
   return +l;
});
```

Without jQuery (using the browsers native `map` method):

```
"1,2,3,4,5,6".split(',').map(function(e) {return +e});
```

Comment: *Array.prototype.map* is not widely supported, it should be feature tested first and an alternative provided if not available.

Comment: There's no point in adding the for solution, @PaulPRO covered it really good. I'm leaving this for the sake of completion only (since it's not mentioned elsewhere)